# phpseclib exec() is returning unformatted text?

Tags: php, linux, phpseclib

I'm trying to execute the below code against a HP C7000 Onboard Administrator

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('OA');

if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$response = $ssh->exec('show server names');

echo $response;
```

Problem is that it displays an unformatted pile of text, which makes trying to get things from it a little more difficult. No newlines, just spaces.

Am I missing somthing?

Thank you

Comment: Try using the function `nl2br`. There probably are newlines but they wont show in a browser.

Comment: Thank You!! You were dead on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($response) . '</pre>';`